# using ESI slower than EAX?

Tags: assembly, x86

This piece of asm is much slower than the corresponding piece using the eax register. Why is that?

```
jmp .l2
.l1:

   dec ESI
.l2:
   cmp ESI, 0
   jne .l1
```

---

```
jmp .l2
.l1:

   dec EAX
.l2:
   cmp EAX, 0
   jne .l1
```

Comment: Why do you think that is's slower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance will depend on what EAX and ESI are being used for, before and after this piece of code runs. Depending on the architecture, the CPU can parallelise instructions that operate on different registers; code that operates on the same register must block.

(I don't have any more specific advice other than to trust the compiler: it knows the right way to allocate registers to take advantage of parallelism, and I don't.)

Comment: So a compiler is god-given? I do have an advice for you: Find something nice to read at http://www.agner.org/optimize/, just look at a disassembly of the object code produced by your "optimizing" compiler and feel eternal pain, look at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/ and never trust your compiler.

Comment: Besides that, your answer is of course basically correct :-) The problem is most likely the time measurement code of the OP.

Comment: Basically I was building a compiler my self and I was comparing the code generated by gcc for comparison and this was basically the only difference. After all though it seems that something going on with my stdin int reading and the buffer. Thanks though.

Comment: @George If you're building your own compiler then definitely read @drhirsch's links. And have fun!

Comment: Wow thanks, great links @drhirsch. Sorry about the question I was getting frustrated, but for no obvious reason my executable was about 15s slower than the other code. =)

Answer (score 1):

,Boath pieces of code has more or less the some excecution speed. You can check the execution speed via execution of instruction **rdtsc** before rutine and after rutine to measure (count) execution CPU clocks. Of course boath rutines must to start with the some value in EAX and ESI register. Do not use a huge loop values becouse the task scheduler can interrupt the current task in the middle of loop execution and you will get wrong result. However if some measiring result deviate a lot than the current task was interrupted by the task scheduler and you must to ignore that result.

EDIT: **TESTs**

Here I have put both tests, so that everybody can check the results:

```
var
  StartTicks                :Int64;
  EndTicks                  :Int64;

    procedure TForm9.ButtonEAXClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      asm
        rdtsc
        mov         dword ptr [StartTicks], eax
        mov         dword ptr [StartTicks + 4], edx
    //Start test
        mov         eax, 10000
    @Loop:
        dec         eax
        cmp         eax, 0
        jnz         @Loop
    //End test
        rdtsc
        mov         dword ptr [EndTicks], eax
        mov         dword ptr [EndTicks + 4], edx
      end;
      caption := IntToStr(EndTicks - StartTicks);
    end;

    procedure TForm9.ButtonESIClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      asm
        rdtsc
        mov         dword ptr [StartTicks], eax
        mov         dword ptr [StartTicks + 4], edx
    //Start test
        mov         esi, 10000
    @Loop:
        dec         esi
        cmp         esi, 0
        jnz         @Loop
    //End test
        rdtsc
        mov         dword ptr [EndTicks], eax
        mov         dword ptr [EndTicks + 4], edx
      end;
      caption := IntToStr(EndTicks - StartTicks);
    end;
```

**10000 loops on modern CPU will not produce any difference between execution of rutine with use EAX or ESI.**

Answer (score 0):

A small effect is also that in some cases instructions using AX/EAX may be shorter.  Not as big a deal as it was WAAAY back in the 8088 day when (due to the 8-bit data bus and slow memory access) the processor wasted a LOT of time just trying to fill the pipeline to run the next instruction.

Answer (score -1):

Speed of registers depends on what are you doing with them, because every register has its own circuitry. For example ecx is connected to counter circuits so it will be faster if used as counter, eax is well connected to the ALU so it's the best register for math tasks. Of course now you can use ecx for math and eax as counter, but in the early processors era programmers hadn't this freedom.
In fact esi is used for memory access, so it is connected "better" (please pass the term, I can't express myself better) to the memory.

Comment: Not true for modern CPUs! Check my answer!

Comment: @GJ: for that I said "in the early processors era". Sorry if I expressed myself badly, English is not my mother tongue.